# Merge JPA is inserting instead of updating

Tags: spring, jpa

Hi everyone I have this issue with merge (jpa) , first of all I read all the answers about my problem but non of theme helped me to find out a solution.
well I have a table resultat that I want to merge in my managedbean(jsf) but when I do that , I get a another row inserted

```
            package com.journaldev.jpa.data;

            import java.util.Date;
            import java.util.HashSet;
            import java.util.Set;

            import javax.persistence.Column;
            import javax.persistence.Entity;
            import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
            import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
            import javax.persistence.Id;
            import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
            import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
            import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
            import javax.persistence.Table;
            import javax.persistence.Temporal;
            import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
            import javax.persistence.Version;

            @Entity
            @Table(name="Resultat")
            public class Resultat {


                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private int resultatID;

                @ManyToOne
                @JoinColumn(name="personneID")
                private Etudiant etudiant;

                @ManyToOne
                @JoinColumn(name="testID")
                private Test test;

                @Column
                private boolean passer;

                @Column
                private int resultat;

                @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
                @Column
                private Date date_passage;



                public int getResultatID() {
                    return resultatID;
                }

                public void setResultatID(int resultatID) {
                    this.resultatID = resultatID;
                }

                public Etudiant getEtudiant() {
                    return etudiant;
                }

                public void setEtudiant(Etudiant etudiant) {
                    this.etudiant = etudiant;
                }

                public Test getTest() {
                    return test;
                }

                public void setTest(Test test) {
                    this.test = test;
                }

                public boolean isPasser() {
                    return passer;
                }

                public void setPasser(boolean passer) {
                    this.passer = passer;
                }

                public int getResultat() {
                    return resultat;
                }

                public void setResultat(int resultat) {
                    this.resultat = resultat;
                }

                public Date getDate_passage() {
                    return date_passage;
                }

                public void setDate_passage(Date date_passage) {
                    this.date_passage = date_passage;
                }






            }
```

And my service class is

```
                public  Resultat findRes(int id)
                {
                    return this.em.find(Resultat.class,id);
                }

                @Transactional
                public Resultat updateR(Resultat emp) {
                    // Save Personne
                    return this.em.merge(emp); 
                }
```

and this is how i use it in my managedbean

```
                 Resultat res = testService.findRes(1);
                 System.out.println("hahowa"+res.getResultatID());
                 res.setResultatID(score);
                 res.setPasser(true); 
                 res= testService.updateR(res);
```

Comment: You're changing the ID, which uniquely identifies your entity. What do you expect? IDs are immutable. You may not change the ID of an entity.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH I'VE SPEND A LOT OF TIME , ON A SELLY PROBLEM